# php mysql escaping characters in INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql

When data is entered into my web forms I use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape the bad stuff and store it in MySQL using PHP.  I now setup a script to create a backup SQL file in case I have to reload the data.

Problem: the extra strings in things like "...Joe\\'s trucking..." in the insert statements are causing my code below to fail.  Is there a better way to automate a backup and restore for mysql?  Or maybe how do I fix the data that is causing the restore to fail at that point?

```
$mysqli_link = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxxx");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$query =".......
LOCK TABLES `tbl_serv_prov` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tbl_serv_prov` DISABLE KEYS */;
$select =" INSERT INTO `tbl_serv_prov` VALUES (17,7,'2013-06-15 04:45:22','Joe\\\'s Trucking','----','N')";
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tbl_serv_prov` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;......";


/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($mysqli_link, $query)) {
   do {
       /* store first result set */
       if ($result = mysqli_store_result($mysqli_link)) {
           //do nothing since there's nothing to handle
           mysqli_free_result($result);
       }
       /* print divider */
       if (mysqli_more_results($mysqli_link)) {
           //I just kept this since it seems useful
           //try removing and see for yourself
       }
   } while (mysqli_next_result($mysqli_link));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) ?

Comment: Use Fred's example, strip the slashes when migrating or displaying the data and escape it when going back in.

Comment: Are you set on doing this via PHP? If you have server access mysqldump will allow you to export your data and send it to a local file on the server.

Comment: Fred.  This makes a lot of sense, but if I take these out wouldn't that then make the ' a string terminator instead of a regular apostrophe?

Comment: maybe the bigger problem is why my code is putting data like "6 O\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'CLOCK" in.  I think it is because I"m escaping characters, but that seems like an excessive amount of \

Comment: @sweaty Hm, very good question. I can't say 100%, but suggest you do try it out to test it and see. Have you consulted the manual on the function? Theoretically, it shouldn't break your code.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're using `mysqli`? They're not supposed to be used together. For backups, use `mysqldump`, don't roll your own tools.

Comment: @tadman Might be a typo on the OP's part.

Comment: @tadman - when I started I was using msyql to insert the data.  I'm in the process of cleaning that up, but that is why I was using msyql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Maybe you've doubly or triply escaped it by accident. I would still suggest using the `mysqldump` tool to get the data out exactly as it is, or `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback.  Please ignore me missing the most straight forward answer to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to let MySQL do the work...

```
shell_exec("mysqldump -hHOST -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3  > db_backup.sql");
```

You can set your filenames to have a date if you want to keep multiple copies.

Edit (to load file):

```
shell_exec("mysql -hHOST -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME < filename");
```

Comment: Vlad  I already have that.  Now I'm just wondering how to get that darn file sql file back loaded into the mysql database?

Comment: Vlad.  Perfect.  Thanks, sorry this was one of those questions I missed the easiest answer